# ViewPager2 пересоздание фрагментов

Tags: java, android, kotlin

У меня есть три фрагмента

```
MainFragment // Фрагмент с ViewPager2
ItemFragment // Фрагмент айтема адаптера ViewPager2, который содержит RecyclerView
PreviewFragment // Фрагмент на который я перехожу после нажатия на любой айтем RecyclerView в ItemFragment
```

Всё бы ничего, но есть проблема.

Когда я перехожу `MainFragment -> PreviewFragment` (именно так, не из ItemFragment) то при возврате назад `ItemFragment` пересоздается с нуля. 
 Оно и понятно ведь в `OnCreateView` я делаю так:

```
   viewPager.adapter = MyAdapter(this)
   // Добавляю айтемы
```

Пробовал сохранять `MyAdapter` вот так:

```
private val adapter: MyAdapter by lazy { 
    MyAdapter(this)
}
```

Но приводит к [крашу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606656/viewpager2-crash), все решения которые там описаны мне не помогали.

Еще пробовал где ни будь сохранять фрагменты, в каком ни будь репозитории и там их кешировать и потом добавлять, но это приводит к куча утечкам в LeakCanary у `ViewPager2`.

В общем то хотелось бы услышать как решается данная проблема, а именно нужно как-то сохранять стейт у айтемов `ViewPager2`, возможно их и правда нужно кешировать где-то, но у меня чё-то не получилось.